# Recaptcha.Net connection error with proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy, recaptcha

I am developing an enterprise system using ASP.NET MVC 5. There I have a `Registration` action with captcha which is powered by `RecaptchaNet` library from NuGet which works with `Google Recaptcha`.

Now, I have encountered a problem. That's the beginning of my registration action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<JsonResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        RecaptchaVerificationHelper recaptchaHelper = this.GetRecaptchaVerificationHelper();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(recaptchaHelper.Response))
        {
            // return error
        }

        RecaptchaVerificationResult recaptchaResult = await recaptchaHelper.VerifyRecaptchaResponseTaskAsync();
        if (recaptchaResult != RecaptchaVerificationResult.Success)
        {
            // return error
        }
```

At line

```
RecaptchaVerificationResult recaptchaResult = await recaptchaHelper.VerifyRecaptchaResponseTaskAsync();
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception text (depth 0): Unable to connect to the remote server
at Recaptcha.Web.RecaptchaVerificationHelper.<VerifyRecaptchaResponseTaskAsync>b__0()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
at BankingClient.Controllers.AccountController.<Register>d__8.MoveNext() in c:\Src\IBRC-SVN\WebClients\BankingClient\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 152

Exception text (depth 1): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 88.204.142.34:443
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

After seaching for the answer at StackOverflow, I have understood that the problem is that I use proxy. I have decompiled `RecaptchaNet` library with `DotPeek` of `Resharper` and here is the code:

```
public Task<RecaptchaVerificationResult> VerifyRecaptchaResponseTaskAsync()
{
    // some code
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("privatekey={0}&remoteip={1}&challenge={2}&response={3}", (object) RecaptchaKeyHelper.ParseKey(this.PrivateKey), (object) this.UserHostAddress, (object) this._Challenge, (object) this.Response));
    Uri requestUri = this.UseSsl ? new Uri("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify", UriKind.Absolute) : new Uri("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify", UriKind.Absolute);

    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = (long)bytes.Length;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    IWebProxy systemWebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
    systemWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    httpWebRequest.Proxy = systemWebProxy;
    httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    string[] strArray = (string[])null;
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        strArray = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');
```

Now, I copy this code to my own class in an empty console application:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("check");
Uri requestUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify", UriKind.Absolute);

HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = (long)bytes.Length;
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
IWebProxy systemWebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
systemWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
httpWebRequest.Proxy = systemWebProxy;
httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream().Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
string[] strArray = (string[])null;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    strArray = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');
```

And it perfectly works. I just spent a bunch of time trying to understand what is going wrong. If it can probably affect something, we have an ActiveDirectory authentication everywhere in an organization including proxy authentication.